# Onsenui - list modifier not working inside .append() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, onsen-ui, modifier

ui and I want to make code something like this:

> `<ons-list id="result"><ons-list-item modifier="tappable">tap</ons-list-item></ons-list>`

I want to do this inside javascript using jquery append().  My code goes like this :

```
var onsList = $("#result");
onsList.append('<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">1</ons-list-item>');
onsList.append('<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">2</ons-list-item>');
onsList.append('<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">3</ons-list-item>');
```

it can append alright but the tappable modifier doesn't work..help me please

Comment: `the tappable modifier doesnt work` Please edit question (click on "edit" button at bottom of question) and describe what you expect/wish, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [compile Onsen UI elements](http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#onscompilefunction) if you add them dynamically. Otherwise they will be just empty HTML tags without any magic behind. Something like this:

```
var elem = $('<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">1</ons-list-item>');
onsList.append(elem);
ons.compile(elem);
```

Notice that the element must be appended before calling `ons.compile()`.

Comment: thanks..its working but i change it a bit i use onsList.innerHTML rather than append..Thank you very much for the help